# Not scaled interaction layer on Konva / Canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, konvajs

I'm writing a simple image editor in React Konva. I generated `<Stage width={500} height={500}>`, but in smaller viewports, I try scale canvas sheet by CSS.

For example:

```
const Component = () => (
    <Div>
        <Stage {...size}> ... </Stage>
    </Div>
)

const Div = styled.div`
  canvas {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
  }
  .konvajs-content {
    width: initial !important;
    height: initial !important;
  }
`;
```

I have noticed that the whole sheet scaling correct, but the interaction layer not. As result, if I have scaled canvas on mobile, I cannot drag and drop elements and hit on elements precisely.

Example: https://youtu.be/ulu_ot5f9Xg

I cannot scale canvas by the viewport. Other features use this canvas and expect a big resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not scale the Konva stage with CSS and you should not change the style of its internals. It may break the hit detection algorithm, also it may reduce the performance of your app a lot.

Instead, you should just read the size of the container DOM element and apply that size to the Stage. If required, you can use `scaleX` and `scaleY` for the stage to adjust the content.

For the demo take a look here: https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Responsive_Canvas.html#Do-you-need-responsive-adaptive-canvas-for-you-desktop-and-mobile-applications

Comment: thank you for your reply! 

I need to save the result of canvas to file in high resolution. How can I do that in mobile resolution if I get a small canvas (for example 360px)?

Comment: When you export the stage to the image you can control the quality and resolution of the result. See https://konvajs.org/docs/data_and_serialization/High-Quality-Export.html#page-title